# Ошибка "Cannot read property 'method' of undefined", что не так?

Tags: node.js, axios

Впервые столкнулся с этой ошибкой, вот мой файл аутентификации и сервера

oauth.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const Axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const querystring = require('querystring');        

const config = require('../config');

var FORGE_CLIENT_ID = 'ZqbXzFL8NMXtovqJrLG0O9f5Ar3nQRoE';
var FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'PM4vPHZGQArq99qn';
const scopes = 'data:read data:write data:create bucket:create bucket:read';

let router = express.Router();
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/oauth', function (req, res) {
  Axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: querystring.stringify({
        client_id: FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        scope: scopes
      })
    })
  })

  module.exports = router
```

А вот файл сервера

server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');           // For web server
const Axios = require('axios');               // A Promised base http client
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // Receive JSON format
const querystring = require('querystring');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const config = require('./config');

const PORT = config.credentials.PORT; // import from bim start.js
var FORGE_CLIENT_ID = 'ZqbXzFL8NMXtovqJrLG0O9f5Ar3nQRoE';
var FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'PM4vPHZGQArq99qn';
const scopes = 'data:read data:write data:create bucket:create bucket:read';

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
})

let server = app.listen(PORT, () => { 
  if (process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID == null || process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET == null) {
    console.log('*****************\nWARNING: Client ID & Client Secret not defined as environment variables.\n*****************');
  }
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); 
});

let access_token = '';
const oauth = app.use('/api/forge', require('./routes/oauth'));
oauth()
  .then(function (response) {
      access_token = response.data.access_token;
      console.log(response);
      console.log(access_token);
      res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/create');
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.send('Failed to authenticate');
    });
```

Может кто-нибудь знает в чём проблема? Я экспортирую файл аутентификации в файл сервера дальше продолжаю создавать промисы. При написании двух файлов в одном месте проблем не возникает. Я использую express & axios. Код ошибки:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\My Works\30.01.Viewer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:139
  debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\My Works\30.01.Viewer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:139:34)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\My Works\30.01.Viewer\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:174:10)
    at app (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\My Works\30.01.Viewer\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:39:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\My Works\30.01.Viewer\server.js:39:1)
```

Comment: Вам же черным по белому написано, что в файле index.js в строке 139, а конкретнее в выражении `ebug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);` у вас переменная `req` не инициализирована (undefined) и стрелочка в нее тычет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я это решил:

server.js

```js
let access_token = '';
var oauth = require('./routes/oauth')
app.get('/api/forge/oauth', function(req, res) {
  oauth()
  .then(function (response) {
      // Success
      // let's save token into the varible access_token
      access_token = response.data.access_token;
      console.log(response);
      console.log(access_token);
      // Then, the app is routed to, which creates a shared bucket for our app.
      res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/create');
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Failed
      console.error(error);
      res.send('Failed to authenticate');
    });
  });
```

oauth.js

```
  module.exports = oauth => {
  return Axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: querystring.stringify({
        client_id: FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        scope: scopes
      })
    })
  }
```